# RegEx Notepad++ Replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a huge XML file with a lot of values in it. I'd like to find all attributes which are not in "" and replace them. So far I can find every occurance but I struggle to replace them.

The bold araes are matches in my XML with the RegEx down below.

```
<color r**=0**, g**=155**, b**=20**>
RegEx: =[0-9][0-9]?
```

Now I want to replace them so they look like this:

```
<color r="0", g="155", b="20">
RegEx: "$&"
```

The problem is that I cannot get rid of "=" in the match, so my result looks like this:

```
<color r="=0", g="=155", ...
```

Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure you do not need to check if you are inside an element node? Then use `=(\d+)` and replace with `="$1"`

Comment: You need a matching group: `=([0-9][0-9]?)`. Anyway, you should not parse XML with regex. Use an XML parser.

Comment: I don't need one. It is my first time using RegEx and it is pretty confusing. So much stuff you can do. ;) But it worked now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex :

```
=(\d{1,3})
```

and Replace to:

```
="$1"
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure those ** were put in an attempt to make those digits bold

Comment: @marvel308 :) . Removed them.

Comment: Yes they were indicators for a bold font. I don't know why this did not work in the end.